# How do I unlock my SSH keys on login in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, password, auto-login

I'm making a new server that will pull backups from multiple sources on a schedule, so I'd like it to connect via SSH using a key.

Setting this up in Ubuntu 14.04 *Desktop* is trivial, you write the appropriate `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host remotehost
    HostName <remotehost.com>
    User <username>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And then when you try to connect via SSH, you get a pop-up prompt to unlock your ssh key, and a checkbox to unlock automatically upon login.

I set up the `~/.ssh/config` file in Ubuntu 14.04 *Server*, attempt to connect, and am prompted for a password. Every time. There is no way to unlock automatically on login, so to set up automation scripts I'd have to manually unlock them on each boot, or leave them insecure by removing the password.

What's the best practice here? I've seen people suggesting that putting no password on your private key was the right solution (how is that safe?,' or alternatively to write scripts automating the set up and running ssh-agent at start, which is a kind of hacky way to do it.

Can SSH keys be unlocked at login in Ubuntu Server?